# Why is NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete not triggered when object is deleted?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Insert (`NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert`)is working from my background thread, from that same thread, using the same managedObjectContext save-merge notification and thus does get saved correctly, delete is not working (visible delete animation in tableviews thus not working).

**Updated, now showing all my code for the problematic SchedulesViewController.m:**

```
#import "SchedulesViewController.h"
#import "CustomScheduleTableViewCell.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "ViewScheduleViewController.h"

@implementation SchedulesViewController {
    NSIndexPath *deleteActionIndexPath;
}

@synthesize fetchedResultsController, managedObjectContext;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (managedObjectContext == nil) { 
        managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }

    self.title = @"Schema's";

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    //storedReminderSchedules = nil;
    //context = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"Schedules viewWillAppear");
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // check if we really have any sections in the managed object:
    //if (!fetchedResultsController.sections.count) return @"Persoonlijk";

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo name];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // check if we really have any sections in the managed object:
    //if (!fetchedResultsController.sections.count) return 0;

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ScheduleCell";
    CustomScheduleTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}


// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)configureCell:(CustomScheduleTableViewCell*)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    // Configure the cell.
    ReminderSchedule *reminderSchedule = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.name.text = reminderSchedule.name;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[[[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] name] hasPrefix:@"Dr."]) {
        ViewScheduleViewController *controller = [[ViewScheduleViewController alloc]init];
        controller.reminderSchedule = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
        controller.context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"EditSchedule" sender:self];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

#pragma mark - ModifyScheduleViewControllerDelegate
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddSchedule"])
    {
        [TestFlight passCheckpoint:@"Add Schedule"];
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        ModifyScheduleViewController *controller = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        controller.delegate = self;
        controller.fetchedResultsController = self.fetchedResultsController;
        [controller.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"EditSchedule"]) {
        [TestFlight passCheckpoint:@"Edit Schedule"];
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        ModifyScheduleViewController *controller = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        controller.delegate = self;
        controller.fetchedResultsController = self.fetchedResultsController;
        controller.reminderSchedule = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
    } 
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ReminderSchedule" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorSection = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sectionName" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptorSection,sortDescriptorName, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionName" cacheName:@"Root"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    return fetchedResultsController;
}    

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
    NSLog(@"didChangeSection");
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: 
            [self.tableView reloadData]; 
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


// Notifies the delegate that section and object changes are about to be processed and notifications will be sent. 
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject 
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type 
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView  insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; 
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:(CustomScheduleTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                    atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView  deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; 
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [self.tableView  deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; 
            [self.tableView  insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] 
                                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; 
            break;      
        default:
            break;
    }   
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
} 

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

**Update**
Extra info:

Inserting and deletion of objects happens from the same thread, they use the same managedObjectContext and use the same save store. In fact, first objects are inserted then others are deleted then there is one save.

I'm saving using NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification that triggers the save merge in AppDelegate.

**Update**
More code:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } 
    }
}

-(void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)saveNotification {
    NSLog(@"Merging and saving");
    if ([NSThread isMainThread])
        [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];
    else
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChanges:) withObject:saveNotification waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

**BacgroundThread.m**

```
AppDelegate *theDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSNotificationCenter *notify = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

NSManagedObjectContext *newMoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[newMoc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[theDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];
```

//Shortened insert section for illustration (insertion works good)

```
ReminderSchedule *reminderSchedule = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:newMoc];
```

//Actual delete section code

```
if ([jsonDict objectForKey:@"deletedSchedules"] != nil) {
    NSArray *deletedSchedules = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"deletedSchedules"];

    for (int i = 0; i < [deletedSchedules count]; i++) {
        NSInteger externalScheduleID = [[deletedSchedules objectAtIndex:i] intValue];

        NSLog(@"Removing schedule %d", externalScheduleID);

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ReminderSchedule" inManagedObjectContext:newMoc];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"externalScheduleID == %d", externalScheduleID];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *result = [newMoc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

        for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in result) {
            [newMoc deleteObject:managedObject];
        }
    }
}
```

//Save after insert and delete

```
NSError *saveError = nil;
if (![newMoc save:&saveError]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [saveError localizedDescription]);
} 


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:theDelegate];
```

**Update**
Doing an insert and delete and then save works. Doing insert by itself works. Doing delete by itself does not worK.

Comment: Are the other callbacks (insert, update) working?

Comment: Yes insert is working fine. Delegate functions get called and insert animation works great.

Comment: I assume that the delete itself is not working (the deleted records still show up in the database). Post the relevant code.

Comment: Delete is working. When the app is restarted, so that the viewController with the NSFetchResultsController is reinitialized, the entries are gone.

Comment: show us the code how you delete and how you merge the changes...

Comment: "In fact, first objects are inserted then others are deleted then there is one save." what happens if you only delete, then save? Do you ever just do a delete then save on its own?

Comment: What happens if you remove the notification observer at the end of the mergeChanges method instead? I do background core data stuff with blocks and gcd so I'm not too familiar with this setup.

Comment: No difference if I remove the removeObserver method. I am using GCD the, the code from BackgroundThread.m sits in a dispatch_queue block.

Comment: @jrturton Doing an insert and delete and then save works. Doing insert by itself works. Doing delete by itself does not worK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure NSNotificationCenter allways gets registered with NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, not only when there is something to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `self.fetchResultsController.delegate = self;` is inside your `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Delegate is set to self. The delegate method wouldnt be called with insert otherwise.